# Autofac constrained binding

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

I am looking at moving from Ninject to Autofac but am struggling to translate one of the useful features - constrained binding through attributes.

I currently have this interface and implementation:

```
public interface IRepository
{
   IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get();
}

public class DBRepository : IRepository
{
   public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get()
   {
    // call the database
   }
}
```

I have a cached implementation that will check in cache and if nothing found, call the db repository. This is passed into the constructor:

```
[DataNeeded]
public class CacheRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly IRepository dataRepo;

    public CacheRepository(IRepository dataRepo)
    {
        this.dataRepo = dataRepo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get()
    {
        // check the cache and if nothing found:
        return this.dataRepo.Get();
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a calling controller that will use the cache to get an object:

```
[CacheNeeded]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepository cacheRepo;

    public CacheRepository(IRepository cacheRepo)
    {
        this.cacheRepo= cacheRepo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Get()
    {
       return this.cacheRepo.Get();
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have reused the interface to add a cache layer over the data repository and this pattern works quite neatly. I have then used some custom attributes to tell Ninject that I require a certain type of IRepository. This is configured as follows:

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<DbRepository>().WhenClassHas<DataNeeded>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<CacheRepository>().WhenClassHas<CacheNeeded>();
```

Is there a way to mimic this behaviour in Autofac?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any neat and concise implementation of such mechanism with Autofac, but maybe you can make use of one of Autofac's [meanings of selecting implementation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices). I'd use keyed services, which in your case would look like this: first, instead of custom attributes you'd need to define an enum

```
enum RepositoryKind {CacheNeeded, DataNeeded}
```

then register components marking them with those that provide Cache or data functionality, for exaple like this:

```
  builder.RegisterType<DbRepository>()
         .Keyed<IRepository>(RepositoryKind.CacheNeeded);

  builder.Register(c => new CacheRepository(c.ResolveKeyed<IRepository(RepositoryKind.CacheNeeded)))
         .Keyed<IRepository>(RepositoryKind.DataNeeded);

  builder.Register(c => new HomeController(c.ResolveKeyed<IRepository>(RepositoryKind.DataNeeded)));
```

The advantage of such an approach is that you don't reveal your implementation details in controller and apply caching in the configuration.